# Product page do not show products image and contents

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my ProductScreen.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import products from "../products";

const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
    const product = products.find(p => p._id === match.params.id);

    return (
        <>
            <Link className="btn btn-dark my-3" to="/">
                Go Back
            </Link>
            <Row>
                <Col md={6}>
                    <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}></Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    );
};
export default ProductScreen;
```

And This is my app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import ProductScreen from "./screens/ProductScreen";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Header />
            <main className="py-3">
                <Container>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route exact path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
                        <Route path="product/${:id}" element={<ProductScreen />} />
                    </Routes>
                </Container>
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Maybe I use the Routes tag wrongly because in the video course I watch, the teacher does not use it. but I use it in the new version, so It is not working without the  tag Then I find it on the internet and use this additional tag.
Anyone please help me I really need to complete this project.
When I run this app and click any product /product/id page is open but nothing is shown[image: This is my home page][image: After I click the image this page is shown but does not show product pics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

I see at least 2 issues and a potential 3rd that often trips up new devs in `react-router-dom`.

1. The product detail route path is malformed and doesn't specify the `id` param correctly.
2. The `ProductScreen` component is accessing an undefined prop. No props are passed to `ProductScreen` so `match` is undefined and should actually be throwing an error when attempting to access further into it to get `params`.
3. The remaining issue is that all route params will *always* be string values, but sometimes (*or oftentimes*) the product id value it's compared against will be a number type. Using strict equality checks will fail. `5 === '5' // false`.

## Solution

1. Fix the route path.

   ```
   <Routes>
     <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
     <Route path="product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} /> // <-- remove template string "stuff"
   </Routes>
   ```
2. Use the `useParams` hook to access the route param.
3. Use a type safe comparison. It's easy to convert everything to strings and use the strict equality check.
4. Keep in mind that `Array.prototype.find` *can/does* return `undefined` is no match is found in the array. The component code should handle this gracefully.

   ```
   import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
   ...

   const ProductScreen = () => {
     const { id } = useParams(); // <-- id is string
     const product = products.find(p => String(p._id) === id); // <-- convert `p._id` to string

     return (
       <>
         <Link className="btn btn-dark my-3" to="/">
           Go Back
         </Link>
         {product
           ? (
             <Row>
               <Col md={6}>
                 <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
               </Col>
               <Col md={3}></Col>
             </Row>
           )
           : <p>Sorry, no match found.</p>
         }
       </>
     );
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
<Route path="product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
```

And in your product screen try to use useParams Hook to get params

```
const {id} = useParams()
console.log(id); // check if you are getting value or not

const product = products.find(p => p._id === +id);
console.log(product) // check is there any product
```

Comment: Thank you for answer  <Route path="product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} /> I change this and I use useParams but can not fix problem. could you change productscreen js Please

Comment: i have edited my answer check that out

Comment: `code` No routes matched location "/product/1" 
overrideMethod @ VM115:249
warning @ router.ts:11
useRoutes @ hooks.tsx:348
Routes @ components.tsx:256
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16141
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20909
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:22342
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27219
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26392
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26303
`code`

Comment: this is console. No routes matched location "/product/1"

Comment: <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
change it to this

Comment: Yes first I change this. I tried with curly braces and witout braces

Comment: Brother do you have anydesk

Comment: can you connect my comp and fix it

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has problems with the PRODUCTSCREEN IMAGE not showing. Go to the products.js to the image path and remove the . before the /. For this to work the images folder must be in the in the public folder. Something like this( '/images/marlin8.jpeg')